# Is there a way to dynamically draw on a canvas with data from a video in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have this function that dynamically draws lines(manual graphing) on a canvas with data from a live feed ROI(region of intrest).

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="display: flex; flex-direction:column">
            <div class="row" style="display: flex">
                <div class="col-lg-8  offset-lg-2">
                    <h3 class="mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
                    <img id="video" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="75%" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="canvas_container" style="position: relative">
                        <p id="time" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 10px; color: rgb(141, 238, 178);"></p>
                        <strong><p id="brightness" style="position: absolute; margin: 10px; color: lightblue;">Brightness: Not Available</p></strong>
                        <canvas id="canvas1" width="840" height="460" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
                        <canvas id="canvas2" width="840" height="460"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4  offset-lg-2">
                    <h3>ROI</h3>
                    <canvas id="canvas3" width="840" height="460"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="col-lg-4  offset-lg-2">
                    <h3>Chart</h3>
                    <canvas id="chart" width="420" height="260"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var video = document.getElementById("video");
            var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
            var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
            var canvas3 = document.getElementById("canvas3");
            var chartCanvas = document.getElementById("chart");
            var brightnessDisplay = document.getElementById("brightness");
            var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
            var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
            var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");
            var chartContext = chartCanvas.getContext("2d");

            setInterval(function() {
                ctx2.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
            }, 33);
        
            var rect = {};
            var isDrawing = false;

            canvas1.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
                var x = e.clientX - canvas1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                var y = e.clientY - canvas1.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                rect.startX = x;
                rect.startY = y;
                isDrawing = true;
            });

            canvas1.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
                if(isDrawing === true) {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
                    rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
                    rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                    ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
                }
            });
            let brightness = 0;
            let percentBrightness = 0;
            let roi;

            chartContext.fillStyle = "#F1F1F1"; // set the background color
            chartContext.fillRect(0, 0, chartCanvas.width, chartCanvas.height); // fill the background
            chartContext.strokeStyle = "blue"; 

            canvas1.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
                isDrawing = false;
                // Get the brightness
                setInterval(function() {
                    var imageData = ctx2.getImageData(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
                    ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, canvas3.width, canvas3.height)
                    roi = generateGrayscale(imageData);
                    ctx3.putImageData(roi, 5, 5);
                    brightness = getBrightness(roi);
                    percentBrightness = (brightness / 255) * 100;
                    brightnessDisplay.setHTML("Brightness: " + percentBrightness);
                }, 33);
            });
            function drawLines() {
                // let data = [100, 150, 200, 175, 125, 50, 25, 75, brightness];
                let data = roi?.data;

                chartContext.clearRect(0, 0, chartCanvas.width, chartCanvas.height);

                for (let i = 0; i < data?.length; i+=4) {
                    const avg = (data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2]) / 3;
                    
                    chartContext.beginPath();
                    chartContext.moveTo(i * (chartCanvas.width / roi.width), chartCanvas.height);
                    chartContext.lineTo(i * (chartCanvas.width / roi.width), chartCanvas.height - avg);
                    chartContext.stroke();
                }

                // requestAnimationFrame(() => drawLines(data));
                setTimeout(() => {
                    requestAnimationFrame(() => drawLines(data));
                  }, 1000 / 30);

            }
            requestAnimationFrame(drawLines);
    
            function generateGrayscale(imageData) {
                var pixels = imageData.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i+=4){
                    const gray = (pixels[i] + pixels[i + 1] + pixels[i + 2]) / 3;
                    pixels[i] = gray;
                    pixels[i + 1] = gray;
                    pixels[i + 2] = gray;
                }
                return imageData;
            }

            function getBrightness(imageData) {
                var pixels = imageData.data;
                var brightness = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i+=4) {
                    brightness += pixels[i];
                }
                // Divide by the total number of pixels to obtain the average grayscale value
                brightness = brightness / (pixels.length / 4);
                return brightness
            }


            // For date display
            setInterval(function(){
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var dateString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString();
                var timeString = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
                var fullString = dateString + " " + timeString;
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = fullString;
            }, 1000);
        </script>
        <style>
            #canvas_container { position: relative; }
            .canvas1 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
            .canvas2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

this does work but after some time(seconds) the live feed freezes and thus the `roi` remains the same. This happens as the `data` gets larger and larger which is expected but I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this without killing the CPU? In python I would maybe move this to a different thread but I don't think `JS` would support this.
Any suggestions are welcomed.

Sample output of what I have
[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the setTimeout?

Comment: yep. It's worse without it

Comment: This is a promising browser technology: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas

Comment: Can you provide some more code?

Comment: lemme read on that.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I've updated the script to include all the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "This happens as the data gets larger and larger which is expected"? Also, why do you pass an argument to drawLines(data) when there's no parameter available?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251657/discussion-between-kostas-minaidis-and-e-k).

Comment: You are starting a new `setInterval` at every `mouseup` event. In this `setInterval` call you are doing something very computationally heavy. After say, 5 *mouseup* events, you're asking to do that heavy computation 155 times per second. If you're on a good machine that's able to do the computation in less than 8ms, that leaves you -300ms(yes, minus) per second that's free to do something else. See the issue?